# MappingException when trying to use Guid with Oracle and NHibernate

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, oracle10g

I am trying to use NHibernate to persist objects using Guids for their Ids with the Oracle10g dialect and am getting the following exception:  `Could not determine type for: MyObject..., for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(ID)` (type is MappingException).

My class looks something like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    ...
```

I've tried several variations, but my mapping XML currently looks something like:

```
<class name="MyObject" table="MY_OBJECT">
  <id column="ID" name="Id"/>
```

The "ID" column in Oracle is of type RAW(16).

What am I doing wrong? I've tried using a custom UserType, but get the same error message.  Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen [mapping oracle raw](http://xmlguy.wordpress.com/2008/04/10/nhibernate-tales-n-mapping-oracle-raw/)

Comment: Interestingly, that's almost identical to how I wrote my `OracleGuidUserType` - but I'm getting the same exception when I use it.  I'll try using some of it's other techniques, like using strings instead of actual `Guid`s.

Comment: Ugh, my error was somewhere completely else in my mapping file.  Thanks for confirming that what I had tried was correct!

Comment: Would your care to let us know where the error was in the mapping file?